# Angular $destroy - Documentation recommends unbinding events manually but code shows otherwise

Tags: angularjs, event-handling

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

> By listening to this($destroy) event, you can remove event listeners that might cause memory leaks. Listeners registered to scopes and elements are automatically cleaned up when they are destroyed, but if you registered a listener on a service, or registered a listener on a DOM node that isn't being deleted, you'll have to clean it up yourself or you risk introducing a memory leak.

Looking at the code of `$destroy` it seems it unbinds eventlisteners:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/d7ecab775ceefcd55a23780d005ce1c39cd8651b/src/ng/rootScope.js#L696

`forEach(this.$$listenerCount, bind(null, decrementListenerCount, this));`

So, why does Angular.js documentation tell me to manually remove event listeners when the `$destroy` event is emitted?

Comment: it tells you to destroy not the listeners but the $timeout or $intervals or $http etc

Comment: No, it states `you can remove event listeners`. That was just an example with `$timeout or $intervals`. There are many more event listeners than that, but they would not need to give an example of each one.

Comment: thats for $rootScope watchers if you have registered any. read the BUT part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Events can be bound in the following ways:

- In markup (named function call bound to a built-in data binding)
- In a directive (anonymous function bound to a custom data binding)
- In a controller (DOM event handler bound to an angular.element)
- In a service (DOM event handler bound to an angular.module)

Angular has the following events:

```
$viewContentLoaded
$includeContentRequested
$includeContentLoaded
$includeContentError
$routeChangeStart
$routeChangeSuccess
$routeChangeError
$routeUpdate
$locationChangeStart
$locationChangeSuccess
$destroy
```

The DOM has the following events:

```
onabort
onautocomplete
onautocompleteerror
oncancel
oncanplay
oncanplaythrough
onchange
onclick
onclose
oncontextmenu
oncuechange
ondblclick
ondrag
ondragend
ondragenter
ondragexit
ondragleave
ondragover
ondragstart
ondrop
ondurationchange
onemptied
onended
oninput
oninvalid
onkeydown
onkeypress
onkeyup
onloadeddata
onloadedmetadata
onloadstart
onmousedown
onmouseenter
onmouseleave
onmousemove
onmouseout
onmouseover
onmouseup
onmousewheel
onpause
onplay
onplaying
onprogress
onratechange
onreset
onseeked
onseeking
onselect
onshow
onsort
onstalled
onsubmit
onsuspend
ontimeupdate
ontoggle
onvolumechange
onwaiting

onblur
onerror
onfocus
onload
onresize
onscroll

onafterprint
onbeforeprint
onbeforeunload
onhashchange
onlanguagechange
onmessage
onoffline
ononline
onpagehide
onpageshow
onpopstate
onstorage
onunload
onreadystatechange
```

**References**

- [HTML Standard: Event handlers on elements, Document objects, and Window objects](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handlers-on-elements,-document-objects,-and-window-objects)
- [HTML 4.01: Intrinsic Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#events)
- [AngularJS Docs: $compile service - Directive Definition Object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object)